# Does this linear system of 5 unknowns and 2 equations have multiple solutions?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

\begin{cases}
x+ 2y - z + w - t  = 0 \\
x - y + z + 3w - 2t  = 0
\end{cases}

Add 1st to the 2nd:

$$2x + y + 4w - 3t = 0 \\
y = -2x - 4w + 3t = 0$$

Substitute y in the 1st:

$$x - 4x - 8w + 6t - z + w - t = 0 \\
z = -3x - 7w + 5t$$

Both z and y in terms of x,w,t. Writing using matrix form:

$$\left[\begin{matrix}
x \\
y \\
z \\
w \\
t \\
\end{matrix}\right] = 
x\left[\begin{matrix}
1 \\
-2 \\
-3 \\
0 \\
0 \\
\end{matrix}\right] + 
w\left[\begin{matrix}
0 \\
-4 \\
-7 \\
1 \\
0 \\
\end{matrix}\right] + 
t\left[\begin{matrix}
0 \\
3 \\
5 \\
0 \\
1 \\
\end{matrix}\right]
$$

Solution $x(1,-2,-3,0,0) + w(0,-4,-7,1,0) + t(0,3,5,0,1)$

The previous question was to check the correctness of that solution. I've multiplied each vector by the matrix formed by the coefficients of the linear system and the result is 0 for all. But now I'm seeing that the choice of isolating y and z was arbitrary, I could have isolated any pair of unknowns. Are all linear combinations of three vectors found this way part of the same set of solutions?

Comment: You have $2$ equations and $5$ variables. That means that the general solution will be in terms of $5-2=3$ free parameters (*if* the two equations you have are not lineary dependent). If you have found a solution in terms of $3$ free parameters then all you have to do is to insert it into the equations are check that it does indeed satisfy it. However it is hard to say if you did it right without any more information. I suggest that you add your problem and solution here then it will be much easier to see if you did it correctly.

Comment: I think it would help to get the question reopened, and an answer, if you showed the actual system you are working on.

Comment: The solution is correct. Yes you are right that the choice to solve for $y,z$ is arbitrary, but that does not matter. You are allowed to pick any variable to solve for. The solution you get by solving for, say, $t$ and $w$ will look at bit different on the surface, but the solution set will nevertheless be the same.